# Destructive operations in scheme environments

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, evaluation, destruction

I'm confused about destructive operations in Scheme. Let's say I have a list and some destructive procedures defined in the global environment:

```
(define a '(a b c))
(define (mutate-obj x)
    (set! x '(mutated)))
(define (mutate-car! x)
    (set-car! x 'mutated))
(define (mutate-cdr! x)
    (set-cdr! x 'mutated))
```

Then we have the following expression evaulation:

```
(mutate-obj! a) a => (a b c)
(mutate-car! a) a => (mutated b c)
(mutate-cdr! a) a => (mutated . mutated)
```

Why isn't `set!` having an effect on `a` outside its procedure when both `set-car!` and `set-cdr!` have? Why isn't the expression on the first line evaluating to `(mutated)`? How does all of this really work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first example isn't working as you imagined. Although both the `x` parameter and the `a` global variable are pointing to the same list, when you execute `(set! x '(mutated))` you simply set `x` (a parameter local to the procedure) to point to a different list, and `a` remains unchanged. It'd be different if you wrote this:

```
(define (mutate-obj)
  (set! a '(mutated)))
```

Now `a` gets mutated inside the procedure. The second and third procedures are modifying the *contents* of the `a` list, also pointed by `x`, so the change gets reflected "outside" once the procedure returns.

Comment: Ok, but how can `set-car!` and `set-cdr!` mutate `a` through `x` then?